# searching a list of [Document] from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, haskell, filter

I'm loading a list of document from a mongodb collection using:

```
let docs = access pipe ReadStaleOk "mydb" (find (select [] "my_collection") >>= rest)
```

Now, I'd like to search the docs list for certain properties after the query has been executed. I need to do it that way because I can't filter in the query, I want to load all documents in one shot, and then filter for what I need when I need it.

Any pointer appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the type of the function you want?

Comment: For the type of the function, I'm thinking `String -> String -> Document` (property -> value -> returns the document matching). I haven't tried much, but I imaging doing some kind of `filter` over the docs, then `filter` over the [Field] till I find the one that match, but not sure if it is the right way... @ThomasM.DuBuisson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function of type `String -> String -> Document` will construct a new document from two strings.  It doesn't strike me as helpful in building a function `[Document] -> t Document` or what I thought you might want of `MonadIO m => Document -> m (Maybe Document)`.

First off, remember a document is just a list of Fields:

```
type Document = [Field]
data Field = Label := Value
type Label = Text
data Value = ... a big sum type like Aeson's value.
```

You haven't told us what properties you want to search for so let's assume you can write a function `goodDocument :: [Field] -> Bool`.  Then you can simply apply this function:

```
docs <- filter goodDocument <$> rest =<< access pipe ReadStaleOk "mydb" (find (select [] "my_collection")
```

To get any more specific you'd have to be more explicit about how you identify good documents.